# how to get calendar format date in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have a field  "timeStamp:2015-12-08T11:58:46.650-06:00" using this I have to display it has Today and also Tue 11:58AM. How to do this in AngularJs

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the built in date filter. So you can display it like this:

```
      {{myDate | date : mediumDate}}
```

In this case 'mediumDate' is one of the built in formats available.
Check out the various formats here.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Iam looking for these kind of formats. 1.Tue 12/8/2015 11:58PM 2.Tue 11:58PM, 3. based on the date ,I have to say Today,yestersday,sunday,lasy week . what kind of filters and formats I have to use?

Comment: Please check out the documentation in the link provided. e.g.   'EEEE': Day in Week,(Sunday-Saturday).  For "today' or 'yesterday' you are going to have to do the calculation yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some simple format with the date filter, but for advanced things, like displaying the date/time relative to a concrete moment, you should try MomentJS, wich can handle that and much more.

The functions you're looking for are documented here: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/

It should be easy to set a custom filter with that. Something like this:

```
app.filter('moment', function() {
    return function(dateString) {
        return moment(dateString).fromNow();
    };
});
```